# Regex: gettings all substrings for repeated named group

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to use a named group to retrieve matches from a repeated pattern.
My code looks like this:

```
import re

pattern = '(?P<single1>[\w]+?)_((?P<multiple>[\w]+?)_)+(?P<single2>[\w]+?)'
example = '000_010_020_030_040'
m = re.match(pattern, example)
print(m.group('multiple'))
```

This will print `030`, because previous matches are discarded. What I need is a way to get a list of all the matches. eg.: `['010', '020', '030']`

The [regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) module seems to offer this feature. However I need a solution without external dependencies

**Edit**

The pattern is generated from user input. The separating characters are not previously known. Neither is the placement of the repeated pattern or the number of non repeated patterns.

**Edit2**

The following is how the solution can be achieved in the regex module:

```
import regex
pattern = '(?P<single1>[\w]+?)_((?P<multiple>[\w]+?)_)+(?P<single2>[\w]+?)'
m = regex.match(pattern, example)
print(m.captures('multiple'))
```

returns `['010', '020', '030']`

Comment: Just split with `_`, get the first as `single1`, the last as `single2` and join the rest into `multiple`. Capturing repeated groups are in most cases redundant.

Comment: I need a more general solution. The underscore separation is just an example.

Comment: Then please provide a real-life example text. Regexes are content-dependent.

Comment: BTW, a "more general solution" means switching to the PyPi regex library. Or show the code emulating that behavior you wrote so far.

Comment: The only hint I can provide: match as you are doing now, but after matching, just rebuild the resulting array by replacing the middle part with a split string.

Answer (score 0):

Try using findall:

```
re.findall( pattern , example )
```

To demonstrate - I've simplified your pattern a bit. The following code:

```
pattern = '\d\d\d'
example = '000_010_020_030_040'
re.findall(pattern, example)
```

Returns a list of all matches:

```
['000', '010', '020', '030', '040']
```

Comment: I think OP needs `['000', ['010', '020', '030'], '040']` as output

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need overlapping patterns. Standart re module does not make it for normal regexps. But you can emulate it by using forward search regexp:

```
re.findall("(?=" + pattern + ")",example)
```

returns array of tuples:

```
[('000', '030_', '030', '0'), ('00', '030_', '030', '0'),
```

('0', '030_', '030', '0'), ('*010', '030*', '030', '0'), ('010', '030_', '030', '0'), ('10', '030_', '030', '0'), ('0', '030_', '030', '0'), ('*020', '030*', '030', '0'), ('020', '030_', '030', '0'), ('20', '030_', '030', '0'), ('0', '030_', '030', '0')]

or

```
re.fintditer("(?=" + pattern + ")",example)
```

returns iterator of match objects with overlapping.

The other option is tu use [regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) module it has overlapping option

```
regex.findall(pattern, example, overlapped=True)
```